# Why is jQuery.parseJSON removing slashes from a JSON string?

Tags: jquery, json

Digging through some project code this evening, I ran across a line of jQuery similar to this:

```
jQuery.parseJSON(jQuery.parseJSON(json_string)));
```

I was curious as to why the calls were nested.  Taking a closer look at the JSON string, I found that it contained slashes (apparently escaping the quotes - this is a PHP project).  The JSON string is similar to this:

```
"[{\"input_index\": 0, \"secondary_index\": 0, \"street_address\": \"14106 Transportation Ave\", \"last_line\": \"Kennedy Building\"}]"
```

I separated the calls like so:

```
var res1 = jQuery.parseJSON(json_string);
var res2 = jQuery.parseJSON(res1);
```

I found that the first call produced another JSON string, with the slashes removed, similar to this:

```
[{"input_index": 0, "secondary_index": 0, "street_address": "14106 Transportation Ave", "last_line": "Kennedy Building"}]
```

The second call to jQuery.parseJSON actually produced a javascript object.

**Why does this occur?**  I would expect the first call to fail.

---

The jQuery [documentation here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) doesn't mention behavior like this.  Granted, I'm still fairly new to jQuery, so I may be missing the obvious.

Comment: Entirely possible, but it still doesn't answer why .parseJSON is behaving this way, right?

Comment: The original string is just like my example, but contains production values which I can't paste here.

Comment: Are you sure it's the jQuery implementation of parseJSON that is doing this, and not the browsers native implementation? Be aware that *"Where the browser provides a native implementation of JSON.parse, jQuery uses it to parse the string."* - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Comment: @Ducain So what is `.parseJSON` not doing that it should be? Your output from the first call is valid JSON. It is also a valid object (not a string). See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/warlock5658/sPL5x/). In one the keys are strings, the other plain variables. Both work the same way in JavaScript. In fact to be JSON, the strings (and keys) have to be surrounded by double quotes. Not sure what you're expecting. Please clarify...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At some point in PHP the JSON is being encoded twice.  Quotes have to be escaped in order to make the JSON valid.  Strings are valid JSON:

```
"any string.  Quotes (\") can be included"
```

This can be encoded repeatedly, but all it would do is add quotes to the outside.

It seems like your PHP code is incorrectly calling `json_encode` twice.  You need to call `$.parseJSON` as many times as `json_encode` is called.

Comment: My question is about the behavior of jQuery.parseJSON: am I misunderstanding your answer?

Comment: @Ducain what do you expect `parseJSON` to do that it's not doing?

Comment: I expected the first call to fail, and I'm unsure in any case why it returns another string instead of an object.

Comment: @Ducain it succeeds because the quotes are properly escaped.  As I said in my answer, a string is valid JSON.  You can use `JSON.parse('"string"')`, which returns `"string"`.  That can't be parsed again, but `"{\"obj\": \"value\"}"` returns `'{"obj": "value"}'` (a string) when parsed, which can in turn be parsed and returns the object.

Comment: @Ducain in order to see this in reverse, call `JSON.stringify` on an object twice

Comment: Thank you for the help, and I hate to belabor this further, but let me ask about what you said there: You can use JSON.parse('"string"'), which returns "string".  That's exactly the part that confuses me, and does still.  That method is supposed to return an object yes?  Why would it return a string in some cases?

Regardless of my confusion about the escaped quotes, that confusion is still the basis of my original question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31257/discussion-between-explosion-pills-and-ducain)